# canvas .stroke() animate draw html5

Tags: jquery, html, canvas

http://jsfiddle.net/jfrazelle/bZec4/3/ how can i make this animate the drawing of the arrow, how do I slow down .stroke(). I want this arrow to be drawn and animated as it is drawn.

```
drawArrow('arrow-1', 50, 50, 100, 10, 100);

function drawArrow(id, sx, sy, ex, ey, fx){
    var arrow = document.getElementById(id);
    var ctx_1 = arrow.getContext('2d');
    ctx_1.clearRect(0, 0, arrow.width, arrow.height);
    ctx_1.beginPath();
    ctx_1.moveTo(10,ey);
    ctx_1.quadraticCurveTo(sx, sy, ex, ey);
    ctx_1.stroke();

    var ang = findAngle(sx, sy, fx, ey);
    drawArrowhead(ctx_1, fx, ey, ang, 15, 15);
}

function drawArrowhead(ctx, locx, locy, angle, sizex, sizey) {
    var hx = sizex / 2;
    var hy = sizey / 2;
    ctx.translate((locx ), (locy));
    ctx.rotate(angle);
    ctx.translate(-hx,-hy);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);    
    ctx.lineTo(0.5*sizex,1.0*hy);
    ctx.lineTo(0.5,1.0*sizey);
    ctx.stroke();
}

// returns radians
function findAngle(sx, sy, ex, ey) {
    // make sx and sy at the zero point
    return Math.atan2((ey - sy) , (ex - sx));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use requestAnimFrame. look [here.](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-animation-stage/)